# What does "spark" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I used this link but I couldn't decide which one to use: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spark_1?q=spark+

"A **spark** for energy reform"

Source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/07/Mexico-could-emerge-as-a-surprise-winner-if-nafta-retooling-works-out.html

Comment: It's a play on words. Spark is both the small flash of light (suggesting something electrical) and a *tiny bit* of progress towards energy reform.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's an answer! :-)

Comment: @Damkerng T: It's only the spark of one.